# Django - Filter queryset with child objects (ForeignKey)

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have 3 Models, and 2 of them correspond to the first one.

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField....
    ...

class Child1(models.Model):
   parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
   ...

class Child2(models.Model):
   parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
   ...
```

Now, in my view I have 2 querysets filtered of `Child1` and `Child2` objects.

Is there a way to retrieve all the `Parent` objects that are in the filtered querysets?

Something like...

```
children1 = Child1.objects.filter(blah=blah)
children2 = Child2.objects.filter(blah=blah)
parents = Parent.objects.filter(self__in=children1 or self__in=children2)
```

**NOTE** The code above does not works at all, it is just the idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes:

```
from django.db.models import Q

children1 = Child1.objects.filter(blah=blah)
children2 = Child2.objects.filter(blah=blah)
parents = Parent.objects.filter(Q(child1__in=children1) | Q(child2__in=children2))
```

see docs:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#in
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: I guessed Q objects will help me, but, is it necessary to use `value list ` or `value` in the children1 and children2 querysets to make this works?

Comment: the `Q` objects are only necessary because you want an `OR` query in the filter... if you want an `AND` query then you can just pass as multiple kwargs to the `filter` method

Comment: you can of course customise the lookup name by setting `related_name` on the FK field back to `Parent` from `Child1` and `Child2` models, otherwise the default is the model name in lowercase as above

Comment: no, values list or values qs for the child sub-query is not necessary as long as you only want to select by primary key id... Django will derive that for you as shown in the example at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#in

Answer (score 2):

1- add a related_name to your child Models :

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField....
    ...

class Child1(models.Model):
   parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='related_Child1')
   title1 =  models.CharField(max_length=30)
   ...

class Child2(models.Model):
   parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='related_Child2')
   title2 =  models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

2- import 'Q lookups' inside your views module :

```
    from django.db.models import Q
```

3-then inside your view you can use filter as the following :

```
    search_words = "test_word"
    chaild1_search = Child1.objects.filter(Q(title1__icontains=search_words))
    chaild2_search = Child2.objects.filter(Q(title2__icontains=search_words))

    queryset_list_parent = Parent.objects.filter(Q(related_Child1__in=chaild1_search )|
                                          Q(related_Child2__in=chaild2_search)
                                          ).distinct()
```

i hope this helpful for you .