# Django filter object with list of values

Tags: ajax, django

I have one field with ManyToManyField and  want to filter my object with list of values.I get this values from dropdown.

my template

```
<form class="" action="." method="get">
  <div class="SearchWithTags">
    <select name="searchcategory" id="TagDropDown">
          {% for k in types_list %}
            <option>{{k.name}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <div class="PlaceForTags">
      <div id="PlaceForTagsId" class="Tags">

      </div>
      <a href="#"><img src="{% static 'assets/search.png' %}"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
    <input id="SendTagArray" type="submit" class="Search" name="startsearch" value="search">
</form>
```

i'm creating array of this values

```
values = [];

$(function() {

$('#TagDropDown').change(function() {
    values.push($('#TagDropDown option:selected').text());
            $('#PlaceForTagsId').append("<div class='tagex'>" +$('#TagDropDown option:selected').text()+"</div>");

});

    $("#SendTagArray").click(function(){
        console.log(values);
        $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: '/sitelink/',
         data: {'tags': values},
        });
    });

});
```

views.py

```
tags = request.GET.getlist('tags', '')
if searchbutt:
    if tags != '':
        search_filter_kw['tags__name__in'] = tags
```

but i have problem that it doesn't send values to my view and tags variable is empty.

Answer (score 1):

How about use `request.GET.getlist('tags[]', '')` ?

#### Result Before Search

[image: before]

#### Result After Search by ajax

[image: after]

---

This example below is how to implement it.

#### Example:

**1. `yourapp/models.py`**

```
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Ref(models.Model):
    foo = models.ManyToManyField(Foo, related_name='ref_foo')
    other = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.other
```

**2. `yourapp/views.py`**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from foo.models import (Foo, Ref)

def fooview(request):
    foos = Foo.objects.all()
    refs = Ref.objects.all()
    return render(
      request, 'foo.html', 
      {'types_list': foos, 'refs': refs}
    )

def search(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        tags = request.GET.getlist('tags[]', '')
        #print(tags)
        if tags != '':
            results = Ref.objects.filter(foo__name__in=tags).distinct()
            return render(
              request, 'search.html', 
              {'results': results, 'tags': tags}
            )
    return render(request, 'search.html', {})
```

**3. `yourapp/urls.py`**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from yourapp.views import (fooview, search)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', fooview, name='foo'),
    url(r'^search/$', search, name='search')
]
```

**3. `templates/foo.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="original-data">
 Original Data:<br />
 {% for ref in refs %}
   <li>{{ ref }} - {% for foo in ref.foo.all %}{{ foo }}, {% endfor %}</li>
 {% endfor %}
</div>
<hr />

<div class="main-search">
  <div class="SearchWithTags">
    <select name="tags" id="TagDropDown">
      <option>Choice categories...</option>
      {% for k in types_list %}
        <option value="{{ k.name }}">{{ k.name }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <div class="PlaceForTags">
      <div id="PlaceForTagsId" class="Tags">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="SendTagArray" class="search">Search...</button>
</div><!-- end /.main-search -->

<div class="main-results">
</div>

<script>
  values = [];
  $(function() {
    $('#TagDropDown').change(function() {
        var val = $('#TagDropDown option:selected').text();
      // check if has duplicate values
      if (values.includes(val) == false){
        values.push(val);
        $('#PlaceForTagsId').append("<div class='tagex'>" +$('#TagDropDown option:selected').text()+"</div>");
      }
    });
    $("#SendTagArray").click(function(){
      console.log(values);
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '{% url "search" %}',
        data: {
          'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}', 
          'tags': values
        },
        success: function(data) {
           $('.main-results').html(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
           console.log(data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**4. `templates/search.html`**

```
<div class="results">
  Result of {{ tags }}:
  <hr />

  {% for result in results %}
    <li>{{ result }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't paste my whole form html, i have another dropdowns in this form, but in this situation i want to filter my object with many tags and it impossible without javascript so when i click my search button it executes ordinary query filter from other dropdowns and javascript to execute this filter with tags. Is it possible that this is  a problem here?

Comment: ofcourse can, please checkout this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28417702/6396981