# How to get (Parent) objects by filtering its child model?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have researched some ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62204684/16607067), [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28417702/16607067))s but didn't get what I want.
So I have two models:
**models.py**

```py
class TvProgram(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512)

class TvProgramSchedule(TimeStampedModel):
    tvprogram = models.ForeignKey(
        to=TvProgram, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    schedule = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want to get Tvprograms (Parent) which its children's schedules are only for the 7 days, In my case I am getting tvprograms with its all children.

Is there a way to retrieve all the Parent objects that are in the filtered querysets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem like that:

```py
from django.db.models import Prefetch

yesterday = timezone.now() - timedelta(days=1)
days_range = [yesterday, yesterday + timedelta(days=8)]

queryset = qs.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('tvprogramschedule_set', queryset=TvProgramSchedule.objects.filter(schedule__range=days_range).order_by('schedule'))
).exclude(tvprogramschedule__lte=0)
```

Answer (score 3):

To retrieve all parent objects that have child objects with a schedule within the last 7 days, you can use Django's queryset filtering with a subquery. Here's an example:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.db.models import Q

# Get the date 7 days ago
date_threshold = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)

# Filter TvProgram objects that have TvProgramSchedule objects with a schedule within the last 7 days
tvprograms = TvProgram.objects.filter(
    Q(tvprogramschedule__schedule__gte=date_threshold) &
    Q(tvprogramschedule__schedule__lte=datetime.now())
).distinct()
```

This will return a queryset of TvProgram objects that have TvProgramSchedule objects with a schedule within the last 7 days. The `distinct()` method

Comment: No, It is returning all schedules not for the last 7 days

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve all parent whose child program scheduled in last 7 days

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_seven_days_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)

parent_programs = TvProgram.objects.filter(
    tvprogramschedule__schedule__gte=date_seven_days_ago
).distinct()
```

and in case you want to find programs that are scheduled for the next 7 days

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_after_seven_days = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=7)

parent_programs = TvProgram.objects.filter(
    tvprogramschedule__schedule__gte=datetime.now(),
    tvprogramschedule__schedule__lte=date_after_seven_days
).distinct()
```

Comment: I tried this, but it returned Parent objects with its all children not for only 7 days